# Activate part warning

Tags: eclipse-rcp

My application is a perspective with two views.
When starting it, the application shows viewA with a table, the viewB is hidden.
When I select an item from the table, opens the viewB, send the item you selected to viewB, and hides the viewA.
I can perform these actions but on the console I have the following warning:
"Prevented recursive attempt to activate part "viewB" while still in the middle of activating part "viewA".
Some help to solve this warning?.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing the work to display "viewB" inside the button click event method? If so, you probably need to queue that work up for the UI thread to do later on by wrapping it in:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your UI update code.
  }
};
```